# Cannot reproduce simple example form the Hood (Haskell Object Observation Debugger) package documentation

Tags: haskell

To get some more insight into the intermediate steps involved in the evaluation of expressions, I would like to give the hood (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hood) package a try.

On the home page (http://ku-fpg.github.io/software/hood/) of the package, there are some examples of the capabilities of hood, namely this example:

```
import Debug.Hood.Observe

ex2 = print
    . reverse
    . (observe "intermediate")
    . reverse
    $ [1..9]
n = runO ex2
```

When I try to run this example I get the following error:

```
hoodTests.hs:10:10: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘1’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: 1
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘[1 .. 9]’
      In the expression:
        print . reverse . (observe "intermediate") . reverse $ [1 .. 9] Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I guess this means that [1..9] should have a clear Type like `Int` or `Float`.

Then I change the script like this:

```
import Debug.Hood.Observe

al :: [Int]
al = [0..9]

ex2 = print
    . reverse
    . (observe "intermediate")
    . reverse
    $ al
n = runO ex2
```

Now the error is gone, but the output is not as expected. Instead of

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

-- intermediate
  9 : 8 : 7 : 6 : 5 : 4 : 3 : 2 : 1 : 0 : []
```

the output is

```
*Main> n
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]


*Main>
```

The package is old I think, it was last updated for ghc-6.x and I use ghc-8. Is this the reason that it does not work or am I missing something else?